# Boxer-turned-politician Vitaly Klitschko pulled out of the race for Ukrainian

Tags: construction

The sentence underlines that Vitaly Klitschko is a former boxer who has now given to politics. Is "boxer-turned-politician" a common construction  to refer to people who change activities, or is it more the  writer's wording ability?

Comment: It's short, and it gets in the interesting but probably irrelevant fact without taking a whole sentence. Typical journalese.

Comment: "Is it a common construction?"  Answer, Yes.  Well-spotted if you're a non-native speaker!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a common construction, especially with words like *turned* and *cum*:

[-turned-politician](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22turned%20politician%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1986,cd_max:2000&lr=lang_en)

[boxer-turned-](https://www.google.com/search?lr=lang_en&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1986%2Ccd_max%3A2000%2Clr%3Alang_1en&tbm=bks&q=%22boxer+turned%22&oq=%22boxer+turned%22&gs_l=serp.3...19595.21305.0.21659.12.12.0.0.0.1.158.1333.2j10.12.0....0...1c.1.38.serp..7.5.571.WFfeLflUR0A)